# If $\{X_t: t\in \mathbb{R_{\geq 0}}\}$ convergences to $X_1$ in probability, then $\{X_t\}$ admits a sequence converging to $X_1$ almost surely.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I want to prove the following claim:

> If $\{X_t: t\in \mathbb{R_{\geq 0}}\}$ convergences to $X_1$ in probability when $t\to 1$, then there is a sequence $\{t_n\}\subset \mathbb{R_{\geq 0}}$ converging to 1 such that $\{X_{t_n}\}$ converges to $X_1$ almost surely.

Since $\{X_t: t\in \mathbb{R_{\geq 0}}\}$ convergences to $X_1$ in probability, we have $$
\forall\ m\in \mathbb N,\ \exists\ \{t_{m,n}\}_n \text{ such that } \lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_{t_{m,n}}-X_1|>\frac{1}{m})=0
$$
I guess that $t_{n,n}$ is the desired sequence, but I don't know how to prove it. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2733329/75923) (especially claim 2).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon \gt0$. Choose $t_n $ so that $$
\mathbb{P}(|X_{t_{n}}-X_1|>\varepsilon)\leq \frac{1}{n^2}.
$$
Apply the first Borel-Cantelli lemma to conclude.